# The system is unable to find the requested action "name1". in yii how to solve it

Tags: php, yii

its controller file

```
class NameFormController extends Controlle
{
    public function actionCreate()

    {
        $model = new NameForm;
        if(isset($_POST['NameForm']))

        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['NameForm'];
            $model->save();

            }
        $this->render('index' ,array('model'=> $model));
    }

}
```

its module file

```
class NameForm extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $name;

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'name' ;
    }


    public function rules()
    {
            return array('name','required');
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array
        ('id'=>'ID',
          'name'=>'Name'
        );
        }
        public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no action named 'name1'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NameFormController` should extend from `Controller`, not `Controlle`

In your `NameFormController`, add the function:

```
public function actionName1() {
    echo 'action Name1()';
}
```

Don't forget to update the access rules to allow access to your new action:

```
public function accessRules() {
    return array(
        array('allow',
            'actions' => array('index', 'view', 'name1'),
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
        array('deny',
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```